# The Boostrap Modal Drop Down is hided behind the Modal

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am using Bootstrap to create a modal for submitting the client information. But I find the Bootstrap Modal Drop down is hided behind the modal. I search some documentations but none of them works. I am using backbonejs to create the `<span>` and it will call the ajax to get all the state names from API. But it should show a drop down menu.
Here is the main codes:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="clientinfoForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h2 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Client Info</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="InfoRequestForm" class="responsive-form" method="POST">
            //The Problem Codes here, it is a input field to let client
            //enter the state information and autocomplete through drop down menu
         <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-6">
            <label>State*</label>
            <input name="state" id="state" type="text" class="large state" value="" />
            <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">1 result is available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.</span>
            <input type="hidden" class="stateId" value="" />
            <input id="stateName" type="hidden" value="" />
                            </div>
```

"ui-helper-hidden-accessible" is a class I created:

```
  .ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Z index to your drop down.